# Delete all files older than, but keep at least one file per folder

Tags: linux, bash

I've a folder structure where backup configs are saved. Every folder has backups for one device, on a day basis. It's organized like this:

```
/backup/
/backup/Area01/
/backup/Area01/Device01/backupfile01
/backup/Area01/Device01/backupfile02
/backup/Area01/Device02/backupfile01
/backup/Area02/Device01/backupfile01
(...)
```

My goal is to:

- Delete only files older than 3 years *BUT*
- If a folder contains files which are ALL older than 3 years, keep one file the newest

In that way I could clean up rom old backups, but have at least one backup config per device, even if very old.
The folder structure should not be touched.

Any suggestion on how do that?

Comment: Find does most if not all you need: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: Ho do that:
`If a folder contains files which are ALL older than 3 years, keep one file the newest`